# wpf calendar control

Tags: wpf, calendar, controls

can i customize the calendar to show more than 6 rows of dates such that other months dates also gets included?

Comment: Asking the same question twice won't get you more answers.

Answer (score 1):

with the standard WPF Calendar control, no, you cannot.

the calendar control is meant to show 6 rows when in "month" mode and 3 in "year" or "decade" mode, no matter what they contain.

if you want to add more dates, you'll have to tweak the control a lot and basically redo the templates and most of the populating behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I have the calendaritem style with me which has a part called PART_MonthView,it has 6 rows defined in it.Why cant i add more row to it and get my calendar populated with more rows?From where is the calendar getting its data?

Comment: "From where is the calendar getting its data?" << THIS is the problem. You can indeed add more rows in the calendar template, but WPF won't know what to do with this. The rows are added in the code behind, so you would have to override the calendar's code behind to populate te added rows. This is what I mean by "redo the templates and most of the populating behaviour.": it is equivalent to recoding most of the calendar class

Comment: don't forget to accept the answer if it answered your question